# Closing a file in Class __exit__ or __del__ method?

Tags: python, file-io, destructor

I want to write a class that is able to write an html file. I now have the following skeleton:

```
class ColorWheel(object):
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params

    def __enter__(self):
        self.f = open('color_wheel.html', 'w')
        self._write_header()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type_unused, value_unused, traceback_unused):
        self._write_footer()
        self.f.close()

    def wheel(self):
        # Code here to write the body of the html file
        self.f.write('BODY HERE')
```

I use this class with:

```
with ColorWheel(params) as cw:
    cw.wheel()
```

The file is exactly written as I expect it to be. However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception ValueError: 'I/O operation on closed file' in <bound method ColorWheel.__del__ of ColorWheel.ColorWheel object at 0x0456A330>> ignored
```

I assume it is trying to close the file while it has already been closed. Is this correct? If so, what would be the proper way to close the file?

Comment: You *also* have a `__del__` method, don't you.

Comment: do you have a `for` outside the `with` ?

Comment: @Kasra: what has that got to do with anything?

Comment: i seen this error when open a file `with` and then dont write the other part of the code inside `with`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also have a `__del__` method trying to *write* to the file after closing it. When `cw` goes out of scope and is cleaned up, the `__del__` hook is called and you appear to try and write to the file at that point.

You can test if a file is closed already with:

```
if not self.f.closed:
    # do something with file
```

Comment: The answer is correct. I want to add a reference to the official documentation that you should read in order to understand the *with* statement: https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Comment: I thought I did not have a __del__ method, but it turns out I do, since I inherited from another class. I didn't show that above, I thought it would be irrelevant. It all makes sense now.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `__del__` will be called as soon as the object goes out of scope ? Or is it implementation dependent ?

Comment: @Sylvain: that's dependent on the implementation. CPython uses reference counting and there the `__del__` is called instantly. But IronPython and Jython use a garbage collection scheme and the call will be delayed.

Comment: @Martijn Concerning Jython: as the JVM does not guaranteed `finalize()` to even be called on program termination, does that imply `__del__` might not be even be called too? I can't find a clear answer for recent version of Jython by googling around...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I'd say it is not guaranteed, but I'm not that familiar with the details of the Jython garbage collection implementation.